# phusion passenger standalone server not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

If I run phusion using:

```
rvmsudo passenger start -p 80
```

[EDIT] the output is

```
>> rvmsudo passenger start -p 80
=============== Phusion Passenger Standalone web server started ===============
PID file: /home/user/site/rails-webpage/tmp/pids/passenger.80.pid
Log file: /home/user/site/rails-webpage/log/passenger.80.log
Environment: development
Accessible via: http://0.0.0.0/

You can stop Phusion Passenger Standalone by pressing Ctrl-C.
===============================================================================
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/therubyracer-0.10.2/ext/v8/v8.so: [BUG]    Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
```

[\EDIT]

on the browser I get a page made by passenger with a lot of not usefull errors. At least for me.

```
The application spawner server exited unexpectedly: Unexpected end-of-file detected.

Exception class:
PhusionPassenger::Rack::ApplicationSpawner::Error

Backtrace:
#   File    Line    Location
0   /var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.18-x86_64-ruby1.8.7-linux-gcc4.6.3-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb 135 in `start'
1   /var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.18-x86_64-ruby1.8.7-linux-gcc4.6.3-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb    253 in `spawn_rack_application'
2   /var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.18-x86_64-ruby1.8.7-linux-gcc4.6.3-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb   132 in `lookup_or_add'
3   /var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.18-x86_64-ruby1.8.7-linux-gcc4.6.3-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb    246 in `spawn_rack_application'
4   /var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.18-x86_64-ruby1.8.7-linux-gcc4.6.3-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb   82  in `synchronize'
5   /var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.18-x86_64-ruby1.8.7-linux-gcc4.6.3-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb   79  in `synchronize'
6   /var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.18-x86_64-ruby1.8.7-linux-gcc4.6.3-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb    244 in `spawn_rack_application'
7   /var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.18-x86_64-ruby1.8.7-linux-gcc4.6.3-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb    137 in `spawn_application'
8   /var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.18-x86_64-ruby1.8.7-linux-gcc4.6.3-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb    275 in `handle_spawn_application'
9   /var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.18-x86_64-ruby1.8.7-linux-gcc4.6.3-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb  357 in `__send__'
10  /var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.18-x86_64-ruby1.8.7-linux-gcc4.6.3-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb  357 in `server_main_loop'
11  /var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.18-x86_64-ruby1.8.7-linux-gcc4.6.3-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb  206 in `start_synchronously'
12  /var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.18-x86_64-ruby1.8.7-linux-gcc4.6.3-1002/support/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server 99
```

the apache error log is:

```
[Thu Jan 03 20:14:47 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Jan 03 20:14:47 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Phusion_Passenger/3.0.18 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jan 03 20:14:53 2013] [error] [client 2.34.83.82] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Thu Jan 03 20:14:55 2013] [error] [client 2.34.83.82] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Thu Jan 03 20:23:46 2013] [error] [client 2.34.83.82] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Thu Jan 03 20:24:50 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

This is driving me insane. I have no idea about where to start. I'm running rails 3.2, ruby 1.9.3-p362, on ubuntu 12.04.

All I want is to deploy my app.

Just to give more information, even though it may not be related, I tried running the apache-passenger-module. All I was able to do was to show the standard apache page, like rails wasn't there. I add the three lines plus the virtualhost, but to no avail. Got tired of trying to find the cause and decided to give a try to the standalone server. But it doesn't work either.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had installed passenger using rvm. Plus had another version of ruby. I removed both the other version, uninstalled passenger, and re-installed it using

```
sudo gem install passenger
```

and it works.

Also, after install, I had to do

```
bundle install
```

to install the passenger gem which has to be on the gemfile.

Comment: Using sudo to install gems is highly unrecommended.