# Error of config assets compress in rails in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, production-environment

At first   in production.rb

```
config.assets.compress = true
```

I change this and i run production mode.
Now all css and js are combined and view as

```
<link href="/assets/application-216f7d9bf69633b46766413cf646b8a5.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
 <script media="all" src="/assets/application-cfa3f1d1e18cc9a8acfb0492bd8ae99e.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But now i want all css and js to load individually not in compress mode 
so i changed

```
config.assets.compress = false
```

Now i want to so my ctrl U as like this

```
<link href="/assets/bootstrap-wysihtml5/core.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/bootstrap-wysihtml5/wysiwyg-color.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/bootstrap-wysihtml5/index.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/app_modules.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/assets.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/authentications.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/companies.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I mean all in uncompress form.  But it is not workin.. again it comes in compress form like before. Do i have to clear cache or where i am missing?

Comment: Did you restarted the server after doing changes ?

Comment: You can flush precompiled files with `rake assets:clean` if necessary.

Comment: yes .. i did service httpd restart after make changes

Comment: @Deefour ya i did but again same problem

Comment: Have you tried the following **production.rb** : `config.assets.precompile += %w( *.css *.js  )`, `config.assets.compress = true`, `config.assets.digest = true` and in **application.rb** : `config.assets.enabled = true`, `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` ?

Answer (score 1):

In your application.rb you also need to disable asset pipeline for production mode.

*application.rb* :

```
# Enable the asset pipeline
config.assets.enabled = false
```

Comment: it gives internal server error and error is like this [Fri Jan 11 13:23:01 2013] [error] [client 172.18.13.118] Premature end of script headers: 
[Fri Jan 11 13:23:15 2013] [error] [client 172.18.13.101] Premature end of script headers: 
. again i changed it but same error

Comment: well if you really want to uncompress the files just for testing what's going on then the best way is to do so in development mode. The production mode is made for deploying without modifications. However, I don't know what's the purpose you want but the above answer should make it. You can read more at - guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: but what is this after i did what u said  tail -f production.log
  <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
  passenger (3.0.18) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
 this error comes. what is this

Comment: this is may be the passenger problem which I have no idea how to deal with. This may help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146904/phusion-passenger-standalone-server-not-working